# Image quantization to a 3-value grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I get an image with a default colormap from a physics modeler as follows:

[image: leelo color map]

I converted it into a 3-value grayscale image, since I know that there are three distinct phases:

[image: 3 value grayscale]

Here is a snippet of my algorithm for figuring out the pixel sorting based on RGB analysis:

```
[RGB_IMAGE_ARRY{j},map] = imread(fname);       
RGB=ind2rgb(RGB_IMAGE_ARRY{j},map);
R=RGB(:,:,1);
G=RGB(:,:,2);
B=RGB(:,:,3);

GRAYSCALE_VALUE=zeros(nx,ny);

for X=1:nx
    for Y=1:ny
             if ((R(X,Y)>0))
                GRAYSCALE_VALUE(X,Y)=128;

             elseif ( ...
                      (R(X,Y)==0)&& ...
                      (G(X,Y)==0)&& ...
                      (B(X,Y)==0.50)...
                    )
                GRAYSCALE_VALUE(X,Y)=0;

             elseif  ( ...
                     (R(X,Y)==0)&& ...
                     (G(X,Y)>=0)&& ...
                     (B(X,Y)>=0.50))
                GRAYSCALE_VALUE(X,Y)=255;
             end
    end
end
```

I did this after trying really hard with the thresholding, quantization functions of MATLAB. It worked for me, but I was wondering if there is a much more elegant solution to get the the same result (instead of cycling through all the pixels through for loops).

Comment: If you're getting an image with the "default colormap", shouldn't it be an indexed image already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops can be replaced with the following two lines through the use of [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7egb6-1):

```
GRAYSCALE_VALUE(R > 0) = 128;
GRAYSCALE_VALUE((R == 0) & (B >= 0.5)) = 255;
```

Comment: Thanks... Is there any other way to achieve the grayscale without even going to the RGB channels ?(e.g using imquantize or threshold)